# How to render component before getInitialProps in Nextjs, Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using nextjs for a project that include dozens of routes. Almost every page includes api call. I am calling an api within `getInitialProps`.
I want api to be called every time a page get loaded or navigated to. I know, on navigation `getInitialProps` runs again on client side.

Things are working fine. But navigation is slow because page Layout doesn't gets loaded until `getInitialProps` doesn't returns some data to its component.

I know there are other functions as well like `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` but that is also not fixing delay in navigation.

**What I was thinking is if there is any way to make components render function runs (even with empty props), before `getInitialProps`, So page layout loads even before api data comes in. Is there anyway to do it?**

In one of my components `getInitialProps`, I am using this code.

```
let curatedCities = [];
if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
  await fetchCuratedCities().then((cities) => {
    if (cities.length) {
      curatedCities = cities;
    }
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

return { curatedCities };
```

Here type of window undefined is required for this particular component, but doing like this, api call won't be working on client side navigation on other pages where api call is required on client side navigation as well.

Again, the main problem is not if data is loading from api call or not, problem is the delay in navigation because components does get rendered before `getInitialProps` returns something.

**Note:** While routing, using `shallow: true` does increase loading time but doesn't call api again within **`getInitialProps`**.

Comment: Simple answer, create an api and use fetch to fetch the data for that page.

Comment: I want api data to be SSR and fetch won't work within getInitialProps, even if it works. It doesn't speed up the navigation in nextjs.

Comment: If the only reason is to hide the external api, you can create an API page within next.js and fetch from that api client side

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Comment: It's rendering slow because each render needs to be processed server-side, and then it renders. If you want fast loading time, you either need to prerender with staticProps, or use the api approach